# Which is safer, Whonix gateway or Torsocks?

Tags: tor, whonix

I've read somewhere that Whonix OS will force all connections through Tor. And I also read about Torsocks who seem to do the same thing.

So what's the difference between them?

And which one is safer to use?

Comment: My opinion is that this is too broad; I think there'd be a better chance of answering (having a Right Answer) if we pinned down the versions, so that people could be sure what software each distribution was using. "Safer to use" is something I'd consider "over the line" into opinion-based territory (or "too broad").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Torsocks works, it's prone to leakage (outbound traffic not through Tor) depending on what the application it's being used on does. Whonix is safer in this regard, as it uses two isolated environments, and the one you run your applications in has no Internet access except through Tor.